# css how to make this div at the bottom of another div

Tags: html, css

This is a jfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/79prY/

This is the result:
[image]

I want the circled div to be at the bottom of the purple div.

The circled div is this div

```
<div class="slNewClass">
                     <div class="details">
                         <span class="content">Service Level</span>
                         <span class="value" id="slSpan" runat="server">0%</span>
                     </div>
                 </div>
```

I tried to do this

```
position:relative;
    bottom:0px;
```

but nothing changed, could u help please

(and please why my solution didn't work?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute; bottom: 0px;` and `position: relative;` on its container.

## **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79prY/4/)**

```
.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

However the absolutely positioned div will not expand the height of its container and will overlap other content if the height is too small.

Using relative positioning moves it x [unit] from its original position. Setting

```
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
```

will move it 0 [unit] upwards from the bottom.

Comment: I don't want to use absolute, because of the downsides you mentioned. isn't there any other solutions?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Is the height of content in the service level div static?

Comment: I could make it static if you want.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli If the height is static you can add a matching amount of padding on the bottom of its container (and add `box-sizing: border-box`). However you still need to decide what to do if the height is not enough to show both the informationTable. Do yo want to scroll the container, reduce font-sizes or some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/79prY/11/)**

**Do the following:**

- set `.slNewClass` div to `position: absolute;` & `bottom: 0px;`
- To avoid the content from overlapping absolute positioned div make `.mainTable` div `box-sizing:` to `border-box` then add add padding bottom like this `padding-bottom: 130px;`

**Note:** Bottom padding should be the same as bottom div height + some extra pixels for breathing space.

Comment: I don't want to use a static values like -66 because the height of the table is not specificed, so maybe it works now but not when adding other elements to the table

Comment: @Marco Dinatsoli here is an alternative solution which is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

### *[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/79prY/10/)*

you just need to add 2 rules.

```
.slNewClass {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0 ; 
}

.mainTable {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

first change the table's style:

```
.informationTableClass {
  height: 100%; /* 60% to 100%*/
  width: 100%;
}
```

then move the div inside the table and change it like this:

```
<tr><td colspan="2" style="height:100%"></td></tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
    <div class="slNewClass">
      <div class="details">
        <span class="content">Service Level</span>
        <span class="value" id="slSpan" runat="server">0%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XaE75/